# Probability of sum of two numbers being prime

Tags: prime-numbers

Suppose we choose two random distinct numbers from $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$.

I learned that the approximate number of primes less than or equal to $n$ is given by

$\frac{n}{ln(n)}$.

Assuming that there are approximately $2n$ possible sums, the number of primes is roughly

$\frac{2n}{ln(2n)}$

and so the probability that the sum of two random numbers is prime is given by

$\frac{2n}{ln(2n)}\cdot\frac{1}{2n} = \frac{1}{ln(2n)}$.

However, it seems like the probability is actually closer to $\frac{1}{ln(n)}$.

I think I might be misunderstanding something.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: the list of possible sums is hardly uniformly distributed.  Just think about the possible sums from rolling two fair dice.

Comment: See this [near duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480251/probability-for-the-sum-of-two-random-numbers-being-a-prime-number)

Comment: The sum of two Uniform distributions on $\{1, ..., n\}$ is Normally distributed in the limit. You can read more about this here https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/discrete-uniform-distribution

Comment: $$\dfrac 1 {\ln(2n)} = \dfrac 1 {\ln(2)+\ln(n)} \mapsto \dfrac 1 {\ln(n)} \text{ for } n >>0.$$

Comment: Are the numbers we sum up random ? Then, the sum is random as well , but if we , for example , sum up two odd numbers greater than $1$ , we never get a prime. We do not get a prime either if the gcd of the summands is greater than $1$.